# Alternative of subInACL to grant permissions to a service?

Tags: sql-server, windows, permissions, sql-grant

Here I have a scenario where I can use subInACL to grant START/STOP/PAUSE permissions to MSSQLSERVER and SQLSERVERAGENT with "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" account .

```
subinacl.exe /service MSSQLSERVER /grant="NT AUTHORITY\MSSQLSERVER"=PTO

subinacl.exe /service SQLSERVERAGENT /grant="NT AUTHORITY\SQLSERVERAGENT"=PTO
```

The above two commands work fine and resolve the Access Denied issue when I start/stop the service using xp_servicecontrol .

However I was looking for an alternative to do the same without having to donwload subInACL and then use it .  Any help on this will be much appreciated!

Comment: To add more for giving a clearer view of the issue : The problem is with the xp_servicecontrol which works fine for 'LocalSystem' account to start the SQLAGENT/MSSQLSERVER services but with the account 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' the execution of xp_servicecontrol shows Access denied error

Comment: [`sc.exe sdset`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742037) sets the security descriptor of a service. In SDDL, `SERVICE_START`  is `RP`, `SERVICE_STOP` is `WP`, and `SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE` is `DT`. From what I read, `xp_servicecontrol` is not supported. Shouldn't you be using `sc.exe` to control a service? Also, the virtual accounts are `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` and `NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT`, but why do the service accounts need explicit rights granted to control their own service?

Comment: @eryksun  :  I can see below permissions already being assigned to MSSQLSERVER and SQLSERVERAGENT when i give sc sdshow 

D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCR
RC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD) 

It looks like the START/STOP Permissions are already assigned , still I get the same error . However with subInACL granting PTO works . Not sure if subInACL does something different internally  .

Comment: There is a specific scenario where I need to reuse the already implemented procedure using xp_servicecontrol to START/STOP SQLSERVERAGENT , can't get it working if the account changes to virtual account . , hence I was looking for something like subInACL to grant permission to service account  . With Virtual accounts xp_servicecontrol shows Access Denied

Comment: And this issue is seen woth both NT Service and NT Authority service accounts

Comment: I wish I could follow all of that. What I do see in the [D]ACL is `(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)`, so services don't have the right to start, stop, or pause this service. [SY]stem and [B]uilt-in [A]dministrators are granted these rights.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun !  I could get it working somehow by giving :

D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCR
RC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;RPWPDT;;;NS)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDW
O;;;WD)